# No cable or WiFi internet after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, ethernet, do-release-upgrade, ubuntu-drivers

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and found that I have no internet access.

My computer is a RoG Strix Scar II, with pretty standard specifications, and upgrading has never been a problem.

I'm not really sure where to look, the output of `ip a` shows the ethernet card and the wireless card as `eno2` with `altname enp3s0` and `wlo1` with `altname wlp0s20f3`, respectively but they don't have a line that says 'valid'.

In the `dmesg` output it shows 'Link is up' for `eno2` and 'enabling device' for `wlo1` so on that level things seem to be OK?

The command `lshw -class network` shows the wireless and Ethernet interfaces as well (Intel Cannon Lake with driver iwlwifi and Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 with driver r8169, respectively), but they are both listed as 'DISABLED'.

After doing `sudo ip link set dev eno2 up` and `sudo ip address show eno2` I get 2 new lines

```
inet6 fe80::692:26ff:fe14:7a0f/64 scope link tentative
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

but there is still no connection: not with `apt`, not with `ping`, not with the browser. And unfortunately, the `up` command does not show anything new for `wlo1`.

The documentation says there are graphical tools to configure the network, but I'm not sure they are included in an upgrade (if you did not have them before the upgrade)? If I do `networkctl` I get the warning: `systemd.networkd is not running, output will be incomplete`. It seems that no network manager is active. Not sure what is required: `networkd`, `netplan`, different things for wired/wireless?

There is no file `/etc/network/interfaces`, should I make one myself? Or are the networks managed differently in 22?

EDIT:

I have solved the case for `eno2` by creating a file `/etc/netplan/01-networkd-all.yaml` (copy-paste from various sources) with the contents

```
# Let networkd manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno2:
      dhcp4: yes
```

so this edit is from my laptop not my phone! It's good that the ethernet is just used when plugged in. For the wifi though, I like the NetworkManager widget in the desktop, and there is also a (now empty) file `01-network-manager-all.yaml`. Would it be possible to do that through NetworkManager? Nothing with that name is running now.

Comment: Your information is only for 20.04 and under.  This doc shows you what you need to know about the config files for networking in Ubuntu 22.04 
 https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration

Comment: Thanks David. I'm still not sure why this hasn't been transferred correctly from 20 to 22. I get the same identifiers with `ip -a`, empty lines for `eno2` and `wlo1` except for their 'altnames' which are `enp3s0` and `wlp0s20f3` respectively. Should I use those in the `interfaces` file?

Comment: I have updated my post with the outputs of `ip` and `lshw`, hopefully that makes sense. The command `ethtool` does not exist.